# alert shows Invalid Shipping method while click continue button in Shipping Information section in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I `removed the shipping method from checkout in magento`.Now I have

```
 Billing Information, Shipping Information, Payment Information and Order Review sections
```

only.When I `click continue button` in `Shipping Information section` an **alert shows Invalid Shipping method**.

If I skip the `Shipping Information section` by select the radio as `Ship to this address` in `Billing Information` it goes to Payment Information section.

```
Why the alert shows Invalid Shipping method while click continue button in Shipping Information section.
```

My **saveShippingAction()** function in **app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php** is:

```
public function saveShippingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_address_id', false);
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShipping($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                $method = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
                $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($method);

                if (!isset($result['error'])) {

                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                }
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }
```

I already `disabled the flat rate`  and `enabled the free shipping` in back end for `shipping method`.

**EDIT**: In local machine these are working well, but in server not working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I got it!!

In **app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php** change the code to

```
 public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
    {
        if (empty($shippingMethod)) {
           // return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
           $shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping'; 
        }
        $rate = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);
        if (!$rate) {
            //return array('error' => -1, 'message' => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invalid shipping method.'));
            $shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
```

For more info: http://sapnandu-magento.blogspot.in/2012/04/magento-onestep-checkout-remove.html

Comment: oops ... are you sure this is the best way !!?

Answer (score 0):

In app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php

```
Modify the line
    $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');

with
    $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'payment', 'review');
```

In your controller I'd also work with $sectionUpdateFunctions

```
Change this section 
    protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
        'payment-method' => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
        'shpping-method' => '_getShippingMeghtoHtml',
        'review' => '_getReviewHtml',
    );
```

with

```
    protected $_sectionUpdateFunctions = array(
        'payment-method' => '_getPaymentMethodsHtml',
        'review' => '_getReviewHtml',
    );
```

This should help you get on track. Please do not edit core files, this should truly be modified in your own module.  But at least copy it over to the path shown to leave the original core files intact.  This will make upgrades significantly easier and is just best practice.